# Wide exec for C/C++

Tags: c++, c, exec, wchar-t

Is there a `wchar_t` version of `exec[lv][pe]` (i.e. an `exec` that uses `wchar_t` as path and `wchar_t` as arguments)?
In `Windows`, I can just do `CreateProcessW(process, cmdline)`, but in `*nix`, I'm stuck (i.e. no pure `POSIX` equivalent).
I'm trying to add `UTF-16` support to my program (an autorun).

Answer (score 4):

There is not. In UNIX, it's customary to use UTF-8 when interacting with the environment.

Comment: Is exec[lv][pe]* UTF-8-aware?

Comment: That's the beauty of UTF-8 -- they don't have to be. Any functions that operate on NULL-terminated bytes (AKA almost every one) will work with UTF-8.

Comment: in Unix, it's customary to use ASCII when interacting with the environment.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem though: the file system on UNIX/Linux is encoding-agnostic. All file names are just "a bunch of bytes"

So if I do a LANG=ja_JAP.EUC_JP, create a file with Japanese name, then I do a LANG=ja_JP.UTF8, when I look at my file name will look like junk, and it will be an invalid UTF-8 string.

You might say: why do that? But imagine you have a system used by hundreds of international users, each of them using Russian/Chinese/Korean/Arabic files, and you have to write a backup application :-(

The "solution" is to ask everybody to set the locale to something.UTF8, but that is just a convention, the system itself does not enforce anything.